How do i remove numbers before text in excel

I want to remove numbers before questions in the column C
the column name is ***QUESTIONS***

Yes TEXTAFTER() function with space as a delimiter!

how ? please elongate with steps

You need to apply the formula in some adjacent column. See in answers

See, what you need to do. Click on any blank cell, i see you have some data on Column D  right hence goto next column E and hit ƒx button, in the search area of the new window write TEXTAFTER hit go and ok, which opens a new window, in the Text parameter of the function select the range, in the delimiter write . (dot and space) and press ok to get desired output

Here is one way of removing the numbers before text for the second column:


• Formula used in cell C1 --> Exclusively works with MS365
=TEXTAFTER(B1:B12,". ")


If you don't have access to the above function then use REPLACE()
=REPLACE(B1:B12,1,FIND(". ",B1:B12)+1,)


Well, if you dont want to use a formula then use FIND+REPLACE feature from Home Tab:
--> FIND : *. 
--> REPLACE : should be left empty
--> Press Replace All

CAVEAT: When using the FIND and REPLACE it will remove anything attached with dot + space --> *.  , found it removes the numbers but for the last one that is 12th, it removes this part as well --> 12. References vs.  should be noted about it


please recheck the ques image

@Maddyplusplus i dont see any difference!

please reload  now

@Maddyplusplus Sir, I have reloaded, and I have seen it. Last time it was in column B and now its in column C, but the data is same. you just need to apply the formula, see i have given the steps in top comments section area. Do you want a demo to see how to apply a formula?

@Maddyplusplus sir, are you able to understand?


Mark the items.

Select Menu: Data > Text to columns (LibreOffice), exist also in Excel
(I don't have access to Excel, currently, so cannot tell where it is; i.e. Data tab in the ribbon?)

Click: [x] Fixed width

Then click the ruler to place a single "new column" marker just before the text.

Click [ OK ]


